# Loggin an Heroku app through heroku run rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, logging

I want to get more detailed logs of my company app.
To do this I have read I can use "heroku run rails console" command.
When I launch it pointing to my remote app, I get:

> /bin/bash: rails: command not found

Do I need to install something on my remote app?
Thank you for the help

Comment: The Rails console most likely has very little to do with your original problem. You would normally examine the logs by using for example `tail -f logs/production.rb`. But there are tons of free (and paid) plugins that make it easier to do this though a web GUI.

Comment: Thanks for the kind response. My original problem is to spot the root cause of Heroku H10 erros. My long in the papertrail do not show details. In other words: it is not possibile from the papertrail logs to spot the root cause of the problem. So I need a tool the get deeper logs related to this kind of problem. In a thread I read abot run rails console, but probably I did not understand anything